# C code for alignment on Intel Core 2 Duo

Tags: c, caching, memory-alignment

I've been given the following c code for alignment

```
struct s *p, *new_p
p = (struct s*) malloc(sizeof(struct s) + BOUND -1);
new_p = (struct s*) (((int) p+BOUND-1) & ~(BOUND -1);
```

where BOUND represents 32 bytes. A line of cache is 32 bytes like in Pentium II and III but I cannot figure out the way p and new_p get aligned. Are both aligned or only new_p?

Also, I have this code for a line of cache of 64 B for a set associative cache with 8 blocks in each set and a size of 32 Kb:

```
int *tempA, *tempB;
...
pA= (int *) malloc (sizeof(int)*N + 63);
tempA = (int *)(((int)pA+63)&~(63));
tempB = (int *)((((int)pA+63)&~(63))+4096+64)
```

Accompanied with this remark: there will be a penalty if you access more than 8 address with a separation of 4 Kb.

The whole doesn't make much sense to me. Any ideas of what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [`_Alignas()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.5) (since C11)?

Casting a pointer to `int` is an invitation to disaster (aka *undefined behaviour*). Just think about a 64 bit machine with 32 bit (standard for most x86). *If* you need arithmetics on pointers, use `uintptr_t` (I would not recommend using `intptr_t`, though). However, even here, arithmetic on the value is still undefined (but very likely safe for platforms with single, linear address space).

Standard note: do **not** cast `void *` as returned by `malloc()`.

**Update:**

Ok, lets take the code above and give it a proper formating and typing:

```
#include <stdint.h>

// align to this boundary (must be power of two!)
#define ALIGN_BOUNDARY 64U
```

Do not use magic numbers in your code! 2 months later you will wonder what that means.

```
int *tempA, *tempB;
```

How are those used?

```
int *pA = malloc (sizeof(int) * N + ALIGN_BOUNDARY - 1);
uintptr_t adjA = ((uintptr_t)pA + (ALIGN_BOUNDARY - 1)) & ~((uintptr_t) (ALIGN_BOUNDARY - 1);
```

This just rounds up the address to the next aligned boundary (here: 64 bytes).

```
tempA = (int *)adjA;
tempB = (int *)(adjA + 4096 + 64)
```

Not sure what the later is good for, but with the `malloc` given, that will result in disaster due to accessing beyond the allocated block if used with the same indexes (0..`N`) as `*pA`.

In any way, I would be very, very careful with this code. Not only it apparently is badly written/documented, but it seems also to contain errors.

Comment: Note that the question is more along the line of what the current code does, Which you'll need to know before finding an an alternative approach.

Comment: @nos: I think the middle (and largest) part is actually relevant. However, I could swap paragraphs if you insist.

Comment: Olaf i find your answer interesting but still don't understand very well the second code and its remark...

Comment: @Rodrigo: If your code runs on a 64 bit platform, that code will likely not work due to `int` being too short to hold a pointer (enable compiler warnings!). Even if, I would be doubtfuil at least, as it is apparently not well designed with all the magic numbers, etc. However, I will explain the basics.

Comment: @Rodrigo: I edited my answer. Note that this might be not a proper answer, but it is too long for a comment and requires structring code, so ..